# automate running cppcheck in tfs builds

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, tfs, cppcheck

I want to make `cppcheck` a part of the build process for `tfs` builds. Is adding a command to the prebuild script the only way to run it? I am using `PowerShell` scripts and I added the line:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe' -ArgumentList $("--xml-version=2 . 2> cppcheck.xml") -NoNewWindow -Wait -WorkingDirectory $projectDirectory
```

However I cannot test it without checking in my changes into Git project. Also running this from Visual Studio 2013, where would I see the results of this check?

Comment: I do not know the answer for your question. But I know that PVS-Studio enables various integration. See documentation: http://www.viva64.com/en/d/

Comment: Adding to the tfs prebuild script is probably the easiest way to run it. Other options would be adding an exec task to the proj file(s). When you say "running this from Visual Studio", are you using the cppcheck plugin?

Comment: yes i installed the visual studio plugin. would i be able to use that from the script somehow? I was calling the exe that i downloaded from the script